# ORA-00907 Missing Right Paranthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

While Processing the query below, I am getting this error of "Missing Right Parenthesis" on SELECT Subquery.

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION, TOTAL_ADMISSION, EMERGENCY, NORMAL      
FROM TABLE (ORDERENTRY.PKG_S04REP00031.ADMISSION_SUMMARY
(P_START_DATE => to_date('01/08/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
P_END_DATE => to_date('01/09/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
P_ADMISSION_TYPE    => 'N',
P_ORDER_LOCATION_ID in (SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM DEFINITIOS.DEPARTMENT),
P_LOCATION_ID => 'K01'));
```

Comment: that is not possible. Although, there could be a workaround in PLSQL. Keep in mind that the table function cannot get more than one value for `p_order_location_id`. To do that , you would need to change the code of the table function.

Comment: can you use PLSQL ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez It is not possible with that syntax; however, it is possible to use an equivalent construction in SQL to call a function for every row of another table. You do not need to use PL/SQL.

Comment: @MTO, thanks for your comment. I know the syntax is not possible. I was asking the OP whether he could use PLSQL, but if you have a solution only in SQL it is nice too.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12c, you can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```sql
SELECT t.DESCRIPTION,
       t.TOTAL_ADMISSION,
       t.EMERGENCY,
       t.NORMAL      
FROM   DEFINITIOS.DEPARTMENT d
       CROSS APPLY TABLE(
         ORDERENTRY.PKG_S04REP00031.ADMISSION_SUMMARY(
           P_START_DATE        => DATE '2021-08-01',
           P_END_DATE          => DATE '2021-09-01',
           P_ADMISSION_TYPE    => 'N',
           P_ORDER_LOCATION_ID => d.description,
           P_LOCATION_ID       => 'K01'
         )
       ) t;
```

or `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`:

```sql
SELECT t.DESCRIPTION,
       t.TOTAL_ADMISSION,
       t.EMERGENCY,
       t.NORMAL      
FROM   DEFINITIOS.DEPARTMENT d
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT *
         FROM   TABLE(
           ORDERENTRY.PKG_S04REP00031.ADMISSION_SUMMARY(
             P_START_DATE        => DATE '2021-08-01',
             P_END_DATE          => DATE '2021-09-01',
             P_ADMISSION_TYPE    => 'N',
             P_ORDER_LOCATION_ID => d.description,
             P_LOCATION_ID       => 'K01'
           )
         )
       ) t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e98b152b4622aa8a7f42f77a4d6a503d)*

Comment: Alternatively use the standard compliant `cross join lateral` instead of the non-standard `cross apply`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've added that option in; however, its more typing as the lateral join requires a `SELECT` rather than directly using the table collection expression.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was so limited.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I had to check the [syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) to make sure there was not another way of doing it but `LATERAL` only comes before a `subquery` (and the syntax doesn't appear to change in [later versions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)).

Answer (score 0):

You can not call a procedure/function with parameter like
P_ORDER_LOCATION_ID in (SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM DEFINITIOS.DEPARTMENT)
it is supposed to be
P_ORDER_LOCATION_ID =>

but still - calling select in procedure/function parameter?